# How to create a polygon in JTS when we have list of coordinate?

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry, jts

We can create a LineString using coordinates list like this:

```
     Geometry g1 = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(coordinates);
```

How can we create a polygon using coordinates list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use these line of codes:

```
 GeometryFactory fact = new GeometryFactory();
 LinearRing linear = new GeometryFactory().createLinearRing(coordinates);
 Polygon poly = new Polygon(linear, null, fact);
```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: If you want to set an especific SRID, you must create a GeometryFactory in this way: GeometryFactory fac = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), _srid_);, replacing _srid_ with your desired SRID.

Answer (score 41):

The accepted answer might have still been valid (still awkward) in 2012 but nowadays you should really do it simply like this:

```
// Create a GeometryFactory if you don't have one already
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

// Simply pass an array of Coordinate or a CoordinateSequence to its method
Polygon polygonFromCoordinates = geometryFactory.createPolygon(coordinates);
```

Comment: But it's create polygon with 3D.How to force to 2D?

Comment: JTS is 2D. Coordinate objects have a third field but it is always NaN. Coordinate is not a Geometry in JTS. Point would be and it only has x and y.

Comment: Yes, bugmenot123 is right, with the current version of JTS you don't need to create a linearRing to create a polygon, a simple createPolygon is enough. Just keep in mind that the coordinates must form a closed ring (the first and the last point are the same) or you will get an exception.